# How can I "snap" scroll to the nearest predefined position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a website that is essentially four divs - each of which is set to the height of the window so that the total document is four times the height of the window.

The idea is that a click on a div advances the scroll by one "window height" - which works fine, like this:

```
// on click event

if(cur_frame<number_slides){
   scrolling = true;
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:window_height*cur_frame},function(){
      scrolling=false;
   });
}
```

After the user scrolls the page manually, however, I'd like to "snap" the position to the nearest multiple of the window height - so a given div is once again centered on the screen. I tried using a timeout, figuring that a small delay would keep it from triggering a thousand times a second...

```
// on scroll event

clearTimeout(scroll_timer);
if(!scrolling) scroll_timer = setTimeout(function(){
   if(cur_scroll!=window_height*(cur_frame-1)) {
      scrolling = true;
      $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop:window_height*(cur_frame-1)},function(){
         scrolling = false;
      });
   }
},100); //20? 400? 1000?
```

...but couldn't strike a balance between the script fighting the user over scroll position, or a seriously long delay that defeats the "snapping" effect.

Any suggestions how this might be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a CSS spec for this, and it is well supported with native rendering and very nice touch behavior except on Chrome: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints

For the laggard browser, there's a polypill: https://github.com/ckrack/scrollsnap-polyfill

See also [How to emulate CSS Scroll Snap Points in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245252/how-to-emulate-css-scroll-snap-points-in-chrome#33149981)

Answer (score 5):

The jquery scrollsnap plugin for this supports down to IE9.

What you're looking for is called "Scroll Snap".

```
<script src="demo/foundation/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.event.special.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.scrollsnap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollsnap({
        snaps: '.snap',
        proximity: 50
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Those jQuery plugins are often user experience killers.

Answer (score 4):

What about using a simple `scrollTo`? Plain Javascript and CSS used, no frameworks or libraries.

Here are two examples, one for vertical scrolling and the other for horizontal scrolling:

- Vertical: https://jsfiddle.net/x9z5tpye/
- Horizontal: https://jsfiddle.net/bwsyn6q4/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to consider a cross-browser javascript re-implementation of the native CSS **Scroll Snap** spec, as already answered here: [How to emulate CSS Scroll Snap Points in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245252/how-to-emulate-css-scroll-snap-points-in-chrome/48683041#48683041), you can use

**[this library](https://github.com/lucafalasco/scroll-snap)**:

The main reason to use this instead of the native css solution is that it works in all modern browsers and has a customizable configuration to allow custom timing in transitions and scrolling detection.

The library re-implements the css snapping feature using vanilla javascript easing functions, and works using the values of the container element's `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft` properties and the *scroll* Event Listener

Here is an example that shows how to use it:

```
import createScrollSnap from 'scroll-snap'

const element = document.getElementById('container')

const { bind, unbind } = createScrollSnap(element, {
  snapDestinationX: '0%',
  snapDestinationY: '90%',
  timeout: 100,
  duration: 300,
  threshold: 0.2,
  snapStop: false,
  easing: easeInOutQuad,
}, () => console.log('snapped'))

// remove the listener 
// unbind();

// re-instantiate the listener 
// bind();
```

Comment: Seems broken in chrome, cannot scroll down, just jumps back to the top

Comment: @Steve what config are you using? I can't replicate the issue (I'm using Chrome 67), do you have the same problems with scroll on [this demo page](https://lucafalasco.github.io/scroll-snap/)?

Comment: Chrome 67 on ubuntu 16.04 - only tried the demo page. Seems to work fine on chrome 67 windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with javascript or for a slightly simpler and older solution you can use page anchors. 
If you change your document.location.hash to an anchor that exists in the page then the browser will scroll to it.
So in your HTML put some anchors in the page:

```
<a name="anchor1" id="anchor1"></a>
```

then in your js put:

```
document.location.hash = "anchor1";
```

Comment: One problem... there's really no "scroll" at all with page anchors.

Comment: The whole point of page anchors is to snap to a location! It does work, I tried it in FF Chrome and IE before I posted the answer just to be sure. Can't believe I got voted down for that!

Comment: I believe what the OP is asking for is a 'quantization' effect.  Once the user is done scrolling, the browser smoothly 'quantizes' the scroll position to the nearest scroll interval.  It's like a 'snap to grid' effect.

Comment: oooh, yes I can't believe I didn't notice that. Sorry Isaac. But you never know, someone might come along to this page looking for a simple way to navigate in-page and find that answer useful so I'll leave it there for posterity.

Comment: Hey thanks, 2019 and it's working, not sure why this answer went -2, i guess they don't know what they are talking about, i just tried and it did the job :)

Comment: @DamonSmith, thank you for your tip!