# How to Scroll page from point to point

Tags: javascript, anchorpoint, scroll-snap

The question is simple. I have a single page website and it has six equal (height and width) sections. I have anchor tags placed in top of these sections so that user can jump directly to the specific section using the menu.

I want the page to scroll between these anchor tags only. So, if a user scrolls the page, it should scroll from anchor tag to anchor tag and not stop in between.

Points to keep in mind:

1. CSS SCROLL SNAP is not working somehow because the design is too complicated. And SCROLL SNAP does not work on anchor tags too.
2. I am using a javascript to achieve it perfectly. But the page scrolls passes the multiple anchors after stopping at each anchor tag for a second. So if I could somehow modify the mousedelta or add some function in the current script to STOP SCROLL AFTER REACHING EVERY ANCHOR TAG until the user scrolls again, then it will do the trick. I'm not well versed in Javascript so plz help me out with this script.

````
var ef = 1;
if (ef === 1) {
(function() {
var delay = false;
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if(delay) return;
delay = true;
setTimeout(function(){delay = false},800)
var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
var XZ = "";
var a = $("a:not([href])").not(XZ.replace(/\b(?=\w)/g, '#'));
if(wd < 0) {
for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
if(t >= 70) break;}}else {
for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
if(t < -70) break;}}
var time = 750; 
var qooqee = 'easeInOutQuad';
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(a[i]).offset().top }, time, qooqee );});})();}}); 
$(window).load(function(){
var ef = 1;
if (ef === 2) {
(function() {
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
var XZ = "";
var a = $("a:not([href])").not(XZ.replace(/\b(?=\w)/g, '.')); 
var x=$(a[a.length-1]).offset();
var m = (x.top) + 10;
var fo= $(window).scrollTop();
fo = fo+500;
var dox=$(a[0]).offset();
var dom = (dox.top) + 200;
var dofo= $(window).scrollTop();
if (dofo < dom){
if(event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
event.preventDefault();
return;}   }
if( fo > m ) {
if(event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
event.preventDefault();
return; } }
$("body").css("opacity","0");
var timing = 750+550; 
var fnz = 750+450; 
setTimeout(function(){ 
$("body").css("opacity","1");
}, timing);
var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
var XZ = "";
var a = $("a:not([href])").not(XZ.replace(/\b(?=\w)/g, '#'));
if(wd < 0) {
for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
if(t >= 70) break;}}else {
for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
if(t < -70) break;}}
setTimeout(function(){  
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(a[i]).offset().top }, 0 );}, fnz);});})();;}});
jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing,{def:"easeOutQuad",swing:function(e,f,a,h,g){return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](e,f,a,h,g)},easeInQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f+a},easeOutQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*(f/=g)*(f-2)+a},easeInOutQuad:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f+a}return -h/2*((--f)*(f-2)-1)+a},easeInCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f+a},easeOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f+1)+a},easeInOutCubic:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f+a}return h/2*((f-=2)*f*f+2)+a},easeInQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f*f+a},easeOutQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f*f-1)+a},easeInOutQuart:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f*f+a}return -h/2*((f-=2)*f*f*f-2)+a},easeInQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*(f/=g)*f*f*f*f+a},easeOutQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*((f=f/g-1)*f*f*f*f+1)+a},easeInOutQuint:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*f*f*f*f*f+a}return h/2*((f-=2)*f*f*f*f+2)+a},easeInSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*Math.cos(f/g*(Math.PI/2))+h+a},easeOutSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*Math.sin(f/g*(Math.PI/2))+a},easeInOutSine:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h/2*(Math.cos(Math.PI*f/g)-1)+a},easeInExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){return(f==0)?a:h*Math.pow(2,10*(f/g-1))+a},easeOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){return(f==g)?a+h:h*(-Math.pow(2,-10*f/g)+1)+a},easeInOutExpo:function(e,f,a,h,g){if(f==0){return a}if(f==g){return a+h}if((f/=g/2)<1){return h/2*Math.pow(2,10*(f-1))+a}return h/2*(-Math.pow(2,-10*--f)+2)+a},easeInCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){return -h*(Math.sqrt(1-(f/=g)*f)-1)+a},easeOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h*Math.sqrt(1-(f=f/g-1)*f)+a},easeInOutCirc:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g/2)<1){return -h/2*(Math.sqrt(1-f*f)-1)+a}return h/2*(Math.sqrt(1-(f-=2)*f)+1)+a},easeInElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k)==1){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*0.3}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}return -(g*Math.pow(2,10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j))+e},easeOutElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k)==1){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*0.3}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}return g*Math.pow(2,-10*h)*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j)+l+e},easeInOutElastic:function(f,h,e,l,k){var i=1.70158;var j=0;var g=l;if(h==0){return e}if((h/=k/2)==2){return e+l}if(!j){j=k*(0.3*1.5)}if(g<Math.abs(l)){g=l;var i=j/4}else{var i=j/(2*Math.PI)*Math.asin(l/g)}if(h<1){return -0.5*(g*Math.pow(2,10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j))+e}return g*Math.pow(2,-10*(h-=1))*Math.sin((h*k-i)*(2*Math.PI)/j)*0.5+l+e},easeInBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}return i*(f/=h)*f*((g+1)*f-g)+a},easeOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}return i*((f=f/h-1)*f*((g+1)*f+g)+1)+a},easeInOutBack:function(e,f,a,i,h,g){if(g==undefined){g=1.70158}if((f/=h/2)<1){return i/2*(f*f*(((g*=(1.525))+1)*f-g))+a}return i/2*((f-=2)*f*(((g*=(1.525))+1)*f+g)+2)+a},easeInBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){return h-jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(e,g-f,0,h,g)+a},easeOutBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){if((f/=g)<(1/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*f*f)+a}else{if(f<(2/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*(f-=(1.5/2.75))*f+0.75)+a}else{if(f<(2.5/2.75)){return h*(7.5625*(f-=(2.25/2.75))*f+0.9375)+a}else{return h*(7.5625*(f-=(2.625/2.75))*f+0.984375)+a}}}},easeInOutBounce:function(e,f,a,h,g){if(f<g/2){return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce(e,f*2,0,h,g)*0.5+a}return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce(e,f*2-g,0,h,g)*0.5+h*0.5+a}}); ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I "snap" scroll to the nearest predefined position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756236/how-can-i-snap-scroll-to-the-nearest-predefined-position)

Comment: You'll probably get more answers if your code is a [mcve] and properly indented with reasonable line lengths.

Comment: @COMRADEDEV CSS Scroll Snap is not working on my website because the page design has multiple elements and it is too complicated to function. Also, I have tried that polyfill but but it requires to recreate the complete website again and it is not easy to integrate it with current website. Also, the Jquery confilcts mess it up.

Comment: So give us the code which is as simple as possible

Comment: @COMRADEDEV How about if you could help me with just the second part of the question? Can we add a few lines of code in this script to modify "mouse scroll input" to make it "half"? Right now, a single scroll makes the page jump through two anchor tags. So if you could make it "read" the input as "half", then it would only jump to 1 anchor at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Code is Very Poorly Formatted I can give you a simple example of how you can achieve "Scrolling Page from point to point"

```js
(function() {
  var delay = false;

  $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

    var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    var a= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if(wd < 0) {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t >= 40) break;
      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t < -20) break;
      }
    }
    
    if(i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
      });
    }
  });
})();
console.clear();
```

```css
body { font: 20pt Sans-Serif; }
a { display:block; color: #00aeff; margin: .3em auto; }
section { min-height: 100vh; background: #252525; color: #fff; padding: 20px; }
```

```html
<section>
  <a name="#A1">Tag #1.</a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</section>
<hr>
<section>
  <a name="#A2">Tag #2.</a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</section>
<hr>
<section>
  <a name="#A3">Tag #3.</a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</section>
<hr>
<section>
  <a name="#A4">Tag #4.</a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</section>
<hr>
<section>
  <a name="#A5">Tag #5.</a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</section>
<hr>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```